# NP and 3-SAT and One Facts

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, np-complete, np, decidable

any expert could help me why this sentence is True?

> if L ∈ NP and L ≤<sub>p</sub> 3−SAT (i.e: reduce L to 3-SAT in poly time) then L is NP-Complete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem.  Try http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is false. Since 3SAT is NP-complete, *every* problem in NP polynomial-time reduces to 3SAT, so if you choose *any* language in NP, then it will polynomial-time reduce to 3SAT. In particular, if you choose the empty language ∅, which is known not to be NP-complete, then ∅ ∈ NP and ∅ reduces toe 3SAT, but ∅ isn't NP-complete.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706726/reduction-to-clique-prob